# eslint rule for multiline function calls

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I'm looking for a `eslint` rule that checks if my function call is correctly formated. That rule should accept function calls that fit one line or calls in which every argument is in separate line. Example below:

```
function myFunction(a, b, c, d) {
  console.log(a, b, c, d);
}

// good
myFunction('lola', 'lolb', 'lolc', 'lold');

// good
myFunction(
  'lola',
  'lolb',
  'lolc',
  'lold'
);

// bad
myFunction('lola',
  'lolb', 'lolc',
  'lold');

// bad
myFunction('lola', 'lolb', 'lolc',
  'lold');

// bad
myFunction('lola', 'lolb', 'lolc',
  'lold'
);

// bad
myFunction(
  'lola',
  'lolb',
  'lolc',
  'lold');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by moving to [Prettier powered ESLint config](https://medium.com/@netczuk/your-last-eslint-config-9e35bace2f99).